# Como ordernar 3 campos clicando nos botões ao lado?

Tags: javascript, angular

Gostaria de fazer com que o botão subisse e descesse, porém ele ta invertendo a ordem do primeiro e de último apenas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
this.changeOrderItems = [
     {id: 1, order:1, checked: true, name:"Organizacional"},
     {id: 2, order:2, checked: true, name:"Colectivo"},
     {id: 3, order:3, checked: true, name:"Individual"}
];

upOrderInput(a, b) {
        return (a.order > b.order && a.checked == true && b.checked === true) ? 1 : -1;
}

downOrderInput(a, b) {
        return (a.order > b.order && a.checked == true && b.checked === true) ? -1 : 1;
}
//Método que deveria mudar a ordem
changeOrder(type, receiveItem) {
    let nodes = [...this.nodes];
           
    if(type == 'up') {
        this.changeOrderItems.sort(this.upOrderInput);
    } else {
         this.changeOrderItems.sort(this.downOrderInput);
    }
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução para mudar a ordem utilizada:

```
 moveUp(item) {
        let index = this.changeOrderItems.findIndex(e => e.order == item.order);
        if (index > 0) {
          let el = this.changeOrderItems[index];
          this.changeOrderItems[index] = this.changeOrderItems[index - 1];
          this.changeOrderItems[index - 1] = el;
        }
      }
      
      // move dwon by 1 postion in Array
 moveDown(item) {

        let index = this.changeOrderItems.findIndex(e => e.order == item.order);
        if (index !== -1 && index < this.changeOrderItems.length - 1) {
          let el = this.changeOrderItems[index];
          this.changeOrderItems[index] = this.changeOrderItems[index + 1];
          this.changeOrderItems[index + 1] = el;
        }
      }

changeOrder(type, receiveItem) {
       let nodes = [...this.nodes];
       
       if(type == 'up') {
            this.moveUp(receiveItem);
            nodes.sort(this.sortOrderByUp);
        } else {
            this.moveDown(receiveItem);
            nodes.sort(this.sortOrderByDown);
        }
      // Observable.of(this.changeOrderItems);
       this.nodes = nodes;
    }
```